# How to enter Login Info for more than one database in Crystal Report using C#?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Here I'm using the following code to enter the Login Details of a Single Database while Loading a Crystal Report.

```
rpt.Load(reportPath);
ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
connectionInfo.DatabaseName = "Northwind";
connectionInfo.UserID = "user";
connectionInfo.Password="user123";
SetDBLogonForReport(connectionInfo,rpt);
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;

 private void SetDBLogonForReport(ConnectionInfo connectionInfo, ReportDocument reportDocument)
{
    Tables tables = reportDocument.Database.Tables;
    foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table table in tables)
    {
        TableLogOnInfo tableLogonInfo = table.LogOnInfo;
        tableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo = connectionInfo;
        table.ApplyLogOnInfo(tableLogonInfo);
    }
}
```

But how i can enter 2 Database's Name and its Login Details in this code to load a Crystal Report...

Comment: why do u want to enter 2 Db's name and login details.. u want to create a report that fetches data simultaneously from 2 Db's.. ?

Comment: Thx for ur reply, Yes I created a Report that fetches data from 2 different Databases, while opening that in viewer it asks for Login Details. So i wanna login using C# code. How I can do that?

Comment: which way you are using to fetch data from database e.g. stored procedure..?

Comment: No, I dont use SP. I fetch from two DataTable from 2 different DataBases, so its asks me login details for 2 times.

Answer (score 0):

in `SetDBLogonForReport` check `If (reportDocument.Database.Tables.Item(i).Name == "TableName")`

then apply

```
tableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = "AltetrnativeName"
tableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName= "AltetrnativeDBName"
tableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo.ReportUser= "AltetrnativeUser"
tableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password= "AltetrnativePsw"
```

if not then use the connectionInfo you passed on. This is for explaining purpose, you can also pass an AlternativeConnectionInfo as parameter.

This way allows you to connect as many BD as you want by table to your report.

If unclear please tell me. I'll be happy to explain in more detailed way.

Comment: Thx for your reply ! where I need to add all these tablelogonInfo ? 
since i already added the connectionInfo out of SetDBLogonForReport and calling them inside SetDBLogonForReport. Can u provide me with complete code structure, it would be more helpful !

Answer (score 0):

From your post I added some example code

```
rpt.Load(reportPath);
ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
connectionInfo.DatabaseName = "Northwind";
connectionInfo.UserID = "user";
connectionInfo.Password="user123";

ConnectionInfo altConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo(); 
altConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "altDataBase";
altConnectionInfo.UserID = "atlUser";
altConnectionInfo.Password="123user123";

SetDBLogonForReport(connectionInfo, altConnectionInfo, rpt);
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;

 private void SetDBLogonForReport(ConnectionInfo connectionInfo, ConnectionInfo altConnectionInfo ReportDocument reportDocument)
{
    Tables tables = reportDocument.Database.Tables;
    foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table table in tables)
    {
        TableLogOnInfo tableLogonInfo = table.LogOnInfo;
        //you can add as much tables as you want but associated with the same connectionInfo
        if (table.Name == "SomeTable") { tableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo = altConnectionInfo; }
        //if you have multiple connections, you could even use switch structure depending on the table name.
        else { tableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo = connectionInfo; }
        //unfortunately, this uses table name property, so you must specify any table name depending on the connection you want to associate with.  

        table.ApplyLogOnInfo(tableLogonInfo);
    }
}
```

To use Crystal Report, the SetDBLogonForReport allows you to add a connectionInfo to each tables. This is the way CR works. I have not be able to find another way to do it (I do not like the use of Hard coded table name)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thx again ! Now i got a clear idea on this, but i hope in altConnectionInfo we need to use altconnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "altDataBase"; not connectionInfo.DatabaseName = "altDataBase"; Even though i'm cant load the report. It says one of my table is not found... :(

Comment: Sorry about that, I edited the post to correct it. Have you tried to re-set datasource location and then verify database? Does the report preview works on dev?

Comment: In development it works fine. But while I run that report in windows appl it says a table is not found, I reset datasource location too, but still getting the same error, that means it accepts only the "ConnectionInfo" not the "altConnectionInfo", if I switch the DB names between the connections infos, the "ConnectionInfo" is always taken.

Comment: Have you removed the "Save data in the report" property? Also clean your report from development (if you added some selection formulas into the report) and be sure you have the right report in your `reportPath` (I got stuck for a long time with this one) ;)

Comment: reportPath is correct.... No Selection Formula... I think the table's conInfo is not proper, because the table itself is not found it says. So the alt DB is not considered...

Comment: ok, so try to set manually the connection info without using an middle object with something like (directly in the SetDBLogonForReport ) : tableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "the other database" ... instead of tableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo = altConnectionInfo. It is possible only one connectionInfo can be used at a time.